# Search for a particular item in place types in google map json data

Tags: java, android, json

I tried to find particular item types in JSON data.
Like

```
 "types": [
        "restaurant",
        "food",
        "lodging",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
 "types": [
        "meal_delivery",
        "restaurant",
        "food",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
      ],
```

Some times restaurant is coming in 0th position sometimes in 1st position.
How to find weather types contains "restaurant" or not

Comment: get the string and compare with restaurant with equalIgnorecase method

Comment: But types  is coming as a jsonArray

Comment: yes you can get the string from array wait i will show an example

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the JSON Array of "types" and check whether it contains "restaurant" -

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("types");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    if("restaurant".equals(arr.get(i).toString())){ 
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is jsonobject get the json array and compare with the required string

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jAry= jObj.getJSONArray("types");
String str="restaurant";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(jAry.get(i).toString())){ 
//do whatever you want
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work for you.

```
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

JSONArray jsonArray= jObj.getJSONArray("types");

boolean s = false;

    if (s==jsonArray.toString().contains("restaurant"))
 {

}
```